# How to dynamically load data into a sliding menu with SlideOverKit?

Tags: c#, mvvm, xamarin.forms

I am creating a cross-platform app using Xamarin Forms 4.0 in VS 2019.

I need a slide up menu who's menu options change depending on the tapped cell date in a calendar selection. I've installed SlideOverKit to attempt to accomplish this. Getting the menu itself works, but changing the options dynamically isn't working.

How should I proceed?

As I said, I've tried passing in the dates, but I also tried saving the date to SecureStorage and requesting the string in the SlideUpMenu's loading method... I believe I may be hitting a 'life cycle of a view' issue.

Here, I pass the selected date from the content page to the slide menu view and a model containing data.

```
   public partial class PublicCalendarPage : MenuContainerPage
    {
        private CalendarModel _calendarModel;
        private bool _showDetails = true;

        public PublicCalendarPage(CalendarModel calendarModel)
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            Content.BackgroundColor = Color.White;
            BindingContext = new PublicCalendarViewModel(this, new ApiService())
            {
                CalendarModel = GetCalendarModel(calendarModel)
            };
            _calendarModel = calendarModel;

            SlideMenu = new ShowMealsView(new DateTime(), calendarModel.CalendarDays);
        }

        private CalendarModel GetCalendarModel(CalendarModel calendarModel)
        {

            //gets the model data via api call
        }

         private void Schedule_OnCellTapped(object sender, CellTappedEventArgs e)
        {
            SlideMenu = new ShowMealsView(e.Datetime, _calendarModel.CalendarDays);
            ShowMenu();
        }
    }
```

Below is the code behind for loading the menu

```
    public partial class ShowMealsView : SlideMenuView
    {
        private readonly List<CalendarDayModel> _calendarDays;

        public ShowMealsView(DateTime eDatetime, List<CalendarDayModel> calendarDaysList)
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            HeightRequest = 80;
            IsFullScreen = true;
            MenuOrientations = MenuOrientation.BottomToTop;
            BackgroundColor = Color.LightGray;
            BackgroundViewColor = Color.Transparent;
            _calendarDays = calendarDaysList;
            if (Device.RuntimePlatform == Device.Android)
                this.HeightRequest += 50;

            var layout = GetLayout(eDatetime);

            Content = layout;

        }

        private Grid GetLayout(DateTime date)
        {
            var layout = new Grid();

            // formats grid layout before the relevant code

            var dinnerGrid = new Grid();
            dinnerGrid.RowDefinitions.Add(new RowDefinition { Height = new GridLength(1, GridUnitType.Star) });
            dinnerGrid.ColumnDefinitions.Add(new ColumnDefinition { Width = new GridLength(10, GridUnitType.Absolute) });
            dinnerGrid.ColumnDefinitions.Add(new ColumnDefinition { Width = new GridLength(1, GridUnitType.Star) });

            var dinnerBox = new BoxView
            {
                VerticalOptions = LayoutOptions.Fill,
                BackgroundColor = Color.FromHex("#f3d176")
            };
            dinnerGrid.Children.Add(dinnerBox, 0, 0);

            //var selectedDate = SecureStorage.GetAsync("SelectedDate").Result;
            var selectedDateTime = date;
            var dinnerLabel = new Label
            {
                Text = "Provide Dinner",
                TextColor = Color.Black,
                HorizontalOptions = LayoutOptions.Center,
                HorizontalTextAlignment = TextAlignment.Center,
                VerticalTextAlignment = TextAlignment.Center,
                VerticalOptions = LayoutOptions.Center
            };

            if (_calendarDays.Any(x => x.ForDay == selectedDateTime.Date && x.Email != null))
            {
                dinnerLabel = new Label
                {
                    Text = $"A DINNER EXISTS!",
                    TextColor = Color.Black,
                    HorizontalOptions = LayoutOptions.Center,
                    HorizontalTextAlignment = TextAlignment.Center,
                    VerticalTextAlignment = TextAlignment.Center,
                    VerticalOptions = LayoutOptions.Center
                };

            }

            dinnerGrid.Children.Add(dinnerLabel, 1, 0);

            var table = new TableView
            {
                Root = new TableRoot { new TableSection { new ViewCell() { View = lunchGrid }, new ViewCell() { View = dinnerGrid } } },
                Intent = TableIntent.Data
            };

            layout.Children.Add(table, 0, 0);

            return layout;
        }
    }
```

Initial loading returns "Provide Dinner"

Once a selected date is made on the content page, the menu selection should include "A DINNER EXISTS!"

However, even though a debug shows that dinnerLabel.Text might equal "A Dinner EXISTS", what is actually showing on screen is always "Provide Dinner"

UPDATE:
I've switched to using ObservableCollection, using that collection as a ListView itemsource because I keep reading that ListView automatically updates its views depending on what data is in the list. (if anything is added or removed)

This does not work, but I'm willing admit I may be doing it wrong as I've never used ListViews...

Essentially I'm still getting ONLY original state of the view which only shows "Provide Dinner"; and again when debugging the property assigned in the model does have the value "A Dinner Exists!" ... so getting the same result with this different method

Answer (score 1):

I think it's a **limitation** of `SlideOverKit` and you can't change SlideMenu dynamically.

I download the sample and use your code to test. I meet the same problem with you.

Then I find a similar issue [here](https://github.com/XAM-Consulting/SlideOverKit/issues/70) on Github, the Author recommend you to `use binding IsVisible to show different view in a single slide menu`.

Later, I find another issue [here](https://github.com/XAM-Consulting/SlideOverKit/issues/17) about `change SlideMenu dynamically` and the author said:

> Well, it cannot be add, cause of OnAppearing will be called after
>   OnElementChanged. How about change the content in MenuView in runtime?
>   Like set IsVisible for ViewA and un visible for ViewB

Comment: That is actually the route I've gone, with the IsVisible boolean. It just seems so... gross.

Comment: @CSharpMinor Did you see the source code?  You can modify it to meet your requirement.